# converting cypress BDD tests to mocha format

Tags: mocha.js, cypress

i have suit of BDD tests written in cypress-typescript, which i would like to convert to mocha format. this is contents of a sample `test.spec.ts` file

```
///<reference types='cypress'/>

describe('mock test', () => {
  console.log('hello i have execuited');
});
```

this is the contents of cypress.jason file-

```
{
  "testFiles": "**.spec.ts",
  "ignoreTestFiles": "cypress/**/*.ts"
}
```

upon execuition of the command `yarn cypress open` via the terminal, i can see the tests under the cypress windown but when i try to run them i get this error message-

```
 No tests found.
Cypress could not detect tests in this file.

Error: The service was stopped
    at C:\Users\------\IdeaProjects\kura\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1335:25
    at C:\Users\------\IdeaProjects\kura\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:666:9
    at Socket.afterClose (C:\Users\------\IdeaProjects\kura\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:644:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

any help highly appreciated

Comment: turns out i had to disable cucumberPreProcessor plugin and Esbuild plug under index.ts file to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `describe()` block is simply a way to group our tests, whereas `it()` blocks are like individual tests.

You need to create individual tests within your `describe` block like so:

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('example to-do app', () => {
    
    it('displays two todo items by default', () => {
        console.log('hello i have execuited');
    })

    it('can add new todo items', () => {
        console.log('hello i have execuited');
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i tried this too. issue turned out to be configuration based. once i disabled the plugins (comment above), the tests started to run fine.